# Deserialize - Loading data from a file

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter

I am using Binary Formatter to save/load data from a file. I have a library system, with two concrete classes - `Users` and `Items` - and an `abstract` class - Library. I am also using two lists:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
List<User> users = new List<User>();


public static void Serialize(object value, string path)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fStream, value);
        }
    }

    public static object Deserialize(string path)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (Stream fStream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            return formatter.Deserialize(fStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Above are the two methods that I'm using to save and load.

To call them from the Program file, I am using this code for saving:

```
string pathItem1 = @"itemList";
string pathUser1 = @"userList";
Library.Serialize(Library.myItems, pathItem1);
Library.Serialize(Library.myUsers, pathUser1);
Console.WriteLine("Serializing...");
```

and this code for loading:

```
string pathItem = @"itemList";
string pathUser = @"userList";
//var deserializedItem 
List<Item> items= (List<Item>)Library.Deserialize(pathItem);
//var deserializedUser = 
List<User> users = (List<User>)Library.Deserialize(pathUser);
Console.WriteLine("Deserializing...");
```

Saving seems to work fine. Loading however isn't. I am getting this error message:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LibrarySystem.User]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LibrarySystem.Item]'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a strange code in your `Serialize` method. You are saving `value` parameter to both pathes: "itemList" and "userList". And actually you are not using path parameter. Your code should looks like this:

```
public static void Serialize(object value, string path)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fStream, value);
    }
}
```

With this implementation your code will work as expected.

Comment: The code now worked without any errors. However, when loading, nothings actually loaded from the file after saving!

Comment: It's strange because I checked this code with simple example and collection (I checked it with 1 and 2 elements) is actually deserialized.

Comment: You can check file existing after Serialize method was called and also check file content (that is enough if the file is not empty/0bytes). Then you may debug code line by line to ensure that your file is accessible in Deserialize method.
Also, if you are saving data from `Library.myUsers` may be you want to load it to the same variable? Then, use `Library.myUsers = (List<User>)Library.Deserialize(pathUser);`

Comment: Thanks Vadim Martynov worked perfectly with the Library.myUsers = (List<User>)Library.Deserialize(pathUser); ! Really appreciate it buddy :)! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Serialize(object value, string path)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(@"itemList", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fStream, value);
    }

    using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(@"userList", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fStream, value);
    }
}
```

You're storing `value` in both `userList` and `itemList`, despite passing the path as a parameter. And since the last call is `Library.Serialize(Library.myUsers, pathUser1)`, what's in `itemList` is a list of `User` objects -- exactly what the error is telling you.

The fix is obvious, simply use the passed path, however you should consider a more robust state storing system. For example you can have a class that contains both lists and you serialize that.

And skipping over a few relatively obvious improvements (`Deserialize` is a prime candidate for a generic function so you don't have to cast it every time for example), one important note is that `NotImplementedException` isn't something vague you can tack your own meaning to, it has a very precise meaning in the context of the .Net framework, and that's a function in your code that you didn't implement for various reasons. The "generic" exception you want is either `ArgumentException` or `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: I changed the code to the way @vadim martynov told me. The code now worked without any errors. However, when loading, nothings actually loaded from the file after saving! - Also changed NotImplementedException to ArgumentException.